# Should I delete the file in Internal memory on Android App?

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

My Android Emulator is not working on my computer, for the time being I am testing my app on real devices. Here is my question.

I am saving some text as a text file (let us name it as **data.txt**) in the App's internal memory. I will share this file with certain apps on the installed device.

The data needs to be saved to the file at frequent intervals (say twice a day). Each time the data is saved under the same file name (**data.txt**).

I am using `FileProvider` to share the file with other applications.

So here is the scenario. 1st set of data is saved under **data.txt**. Should I delete this file after sharing? so that the 2nd set of data gets saved under the same file name or does the application takes care of this issue automatically (by simply replacing the file **data.txt** containing 1st data with the file **data.txt** containing the 2nd data)?

Comment: Can you post your code where are you sharing the file @Traveller

Comment: it depends on how you are writing the file (data.txt) if you `append` then you have to clear/delete the file after sharing, if you just `write` into the file, then it will be overwritten by the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data will be overwritten in file when u will write in the code if u look at the constructor of  `FileOutputStream(String path, boolean append)`  the Boolean value is to handle either you want to append the file or overwrite the existing file(by default this value is false means it will surely overwrite data ) . So i don't think there is a need to delete your file

Comment: Currently, I am overwriting the existing file. Does overwriting a file (be it a text file or image file or anything else) create some kind of cache or space consumption of some kind? (bear with my stupid question - just want to correct my understanding)

Comment: cache for what i m sorry cant understand ya ? well  it just remove all the data in that file and then just flush all that data from the output stream to that file.

Comment: i think you should read about IO streams and there bridge classes like FileInputStream and Fileoutoutstream etc  for more info.